# Error in getting the 'top' position property of dropped Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, typeerror, jsplumb

I'm working with a project where I have to drag and drop elements and perform some further actions on these elements. Currently I'm trying to get the position of the elements dropped on the container but am getting the following error in the debugger.

**Error**

> trail.js:262 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

**Method in Context**

```
function saveFlowchart(){
    var nodes = [];

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Code in Context to the question//

    var matches = [];
    var searchEles = document.getElementById("container").children;
    for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) 
    {
        matches.push(searchEles[i]);
        alert("elements: "+ searchEles[i].id);
        var idOfEl = searchEles[i].id;

        var $element = $(idOfEl);
        var position = $element.position();
        position.bottom = position.top + $element.height();
        position.right = position.left + $element.width();
        alert("Top position: " + position.top + "\nLeft position: " + position.left + "\nBottom position: " + position.bottom + "\nRight position: " + position.right);
    }    
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $(".node").each(function (idx, elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        var endpoints = jsPlumb.getEndpoints($elem.attr('id'));
        console.log('endpoints of '+$elem.attr('id'));
        console.log(endpoints);
        nodes.push({
            blockId: $elem.attr('id'),
            nodetype: $elem.attr('data-nodetype'),
            positionX: parseInt($elem.css("left"), 10),
            positionY: parseInt($elem.css("top"), 10)
        });
    });
    var connections = [];
    $.each(jsPlumb.getConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
        connections.push({
            connectionId: connection.id,
            pageSourceId: connection.sourceId,
            pageTargetId: connection.targetId
        });
    });

    var flowChart = {};
    flowChart.nodes = nodes;
    flowChart.connections = connections;
    flowChart.numberOfElements = numberOfElements;

    var flowChartJson = JSON.stringify(flowChart);
    //console.log(flowChartJson);

    $('#jsonOutput').val(flowChartJson);
}
```

This method saves the connections and outputs it in a json format. But I need the custom made elements to be regenerated as well. That is why I'm trying to get there positions and regenerate them so that I can recreate the flowchart created.

[image: error]

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might help

**Previous line of Code**

```
var $element = $(idOfEl);
```

**Changed as**

```
 var $element = $("#" + searchEles[i].id);
```